# Use Node.js' fs.readFile() to return the line in which a string appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm searching a large external file of n-grams (about 1 million lines) for instances of a specific string and would like to be able to return the whole line from the file where that string appears. Wondering if and how this might be possible.
Here's my code at the moment:

```
 composeLines = function(importantWords, cb) {
    var word = importantWords.shift();

    fs.readFile("./w5_.txt", function(err, cont) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("String"+(cont.indexOf(word)>-1 ? " " : " not ")+"found");

      cb(importantWords);
    });

  };
```

With this code I'm able to determine if the file `w5_.txt` contains some string which is great but I need to be able to get the n-gram it pertains to. E.g. searching for "design" would return the n-gram "a   part    of  the design" from the file.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression:

```
// Make sure `word` is properly escaped first

// 'm' allows '^' and '$' to match line boundaries or
// start and beginning of the input (respectively)
var re = new RegExp('^.*' + word + '.*$', 'm');
var m = re.exec(cont);
if (m)
  console.log('Word %j found on line: %j', word, m[0]);
else
  console.log('Word %j not found', word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are millions of lines you should read line by line somehow like that:

```
var word = importantWords.shift();

var matchCount = 0;
var lineCount  = 0;

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.in')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  lineCount++;
  if(-1 < line.indexOf(word)){
    console.log(line);
    matchCount++;
  }
});
```